# How to shuffle rows with keeping two fields in original order?

Tags: algorithm

I have array of rows with four fields:

GROUP,NAME,KEY,VALUE

I need to "shuffle" this array, but resulting array should comply to following rule: every KEY-VALUE pair having same GROUP should have the same order as in original array

Comment: But not the NAME? Curious.

Comment: Do you need an algorithm which works in place, or is it possible to generate a new array in shuffled order?

Comment: memory is not an issue, array is not very big, so any way will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible algorithm, which requires an auxiliary array of the same size as the original array. It's O(N), but it makes several passes over the original array.

1. Using a [stable counting sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), make a copy of the original array sorted by GROUP. Keep the histogram for use in step 3.
2. Use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the original array in place.
3. Make a final pass over the shuffled array created in step 2. For each row, replace the `KEY` and `VALUE` entries with the next unused `KEY` and `VALUE` entries from the sorted array created in step 1.

The counting sort algorithm assumes that the `GROUP` values are integers in a small range, ideally smaller than the total number of rows in the original array. If this is not the case -- either the groups are not integers or they don't have a restricted size -- then the original histogram for the counting sort can be created by placing the `GROUP` values in a  hash-table. The hash-table cannot have more than `N` entries, so it requires O(N) space and expected O(N) time to create.

If you are planning to repeatedly shuffle the same array, then you should keep the sorted array and a copy of the histogram, since the construction of these auxiliary structures is more than half the time of producing a shuffle.

Comment: I got it, there is no escape of final pass. So, I made it in more rough way - I added ORDER column, 1 to N for each GROUP, then shuffle, then search for pair for every GROUP-KEY. If ORDER in pair is not even, I just swap rows. Thanks everyone